# Update table with a lot of rows with random values

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to update a table with random values from other table, like this

```
update users u
    set first_name = (select firstname from temp_names tn where u.id is not null order by random() limit 1),
        last_name = (select lastname from temp_names where u.id is not null order by random() limit 1);
```

But the table users has 500k+ rows, which is not a sustainable way of doing this.

On a more declarative way, I want to update the first_name and last_name from each row with random values I get from the temp_names table. I want to randomly get the value from there and update it. Whenever I try to run this, it takes ages to not complete. How can I make it run a little bit more faster?

Comment: Depending on how many values there are in temp_names (assuming not too many), you could read them into an array in memory via a CTE, then the update part can set the name to the value of that array at a random index - you'd need to make sure your random calc returns you integers up to the size of the array.

Comment: CTE? 
Nop, there arent that many values onto the temp_names fields. I can

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mockup of how you can do it with a CTE. I don't know how good the performance would be but I suspect it will be better than how you're currently doing it.

Setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE temp_names (firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT);

INSERT INTO temp_names
VALUES
('bob', 'lob'),
('joe', 'blow'),
('jane', 'doe');

CREATE TABLE real_names (id INTEGER, first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT);

INSERT INTO real_names (id, first_name, last_name)
VALUES
(1, 'sdsd', 'dfgdfg'),
(2, 'sdsd', 'dfgdfg'),
(3, 'sdsd', 'dfgdfg'),
(4, 'sdsd', 'dfgdfg'),
(NULL, 'dddd', 'sssss');
```

Query:

```sql
WITH tn AS (
    SELECT
        ARRAY_AGG(firstname) AS firstnames,
        ARRAY_AGG(lastname) AS lastnames,
        COUNT(*) AS howmany
    FROM temp_names
)
UPDATE real_names
SET
    first_name = firstnames[floor(random() * tn.howmany + 1)],
    last_name = lastnames[floor(random() * tn.howmany + 1)]
FROM tn
WHERE id IS NOT NULL;
```

What the `real_names` table look like after the above is run (obviously it differs each run since it's random):

```
| id  | first_name | last_name |
| --- | ---------- | --------- |
|     | dddd       | sssss     |
| 1   | jane       | lob       |
| 2   | joe        | doe       |
| 3   | bob        | blow      |
| 4   | joe        | lob       |
```

Basically, create the arrays and calculate length ahead of time/as a one-off, then you can just access random indexes in those arrays to get the names rather than re-reading the table and resorting etc each time. Not sure about the whole NULL id thing, I might have misinterpreted it.

Comment: still running that, it has been 10 mins, lets see the result